# $_POST doesnt send empty checkboxgroup

Tags: php, checkbox

I have been working on a contact form for a website and I got this problem:
I have 4 checkboxgroups, every each of them have at least 3 checkboxes that are available to check. We don't want them to be required to send the email. So the code is this:

```
$CheckboxGroup1 = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $attending = $_POST['attending'];
    $CheckboxGroup1 = isset($_POST['CheckboxGroup1']) ? $_POST['CheckboxGroup1'] : 'Nothing checked';
```

HTML:

```
 <h4>What kind of set-up would you like?</h4>
 <p>Additional fees may apply for living room/specialty set-ups.</p>
 <p>
     <div class="inline-field">
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1[]" value="Living Room">
            Living Room
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1[]" value="Conference Room">
            Conference Room
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1[]" value="Other">
            Other (please specify at the end of the form)
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>
</p>
```

When none of the checkboxes is selected I get the message "Nothing checked" and when one of them is selected I get the value of it. The problem is when I select more than one, I get this in my email: 
**What kind of set-up will you like?: Array** (not the name of those selected).

I do not know what I have to change to make it work the right way.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change below line

Your code

```
$CheckboxGroup1 = isset($_POST['CheckboxGroup1']) ? $_POST['CheckboxGroup1'] :  'Nothing checked';
```

Change it to

```
if( isset($_POST['CheckboxGroup1']))
{
 $CheckboxGroup1 =implode(", ",$_POST['CheckboxGroup1']);
}
else{
  $CheckboxGroup1="Nothing checked";
}
```

Comment: Welcome @dileoh :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot print array with `echo`. `Echo`ing array will give you string `Array`. Simple way in your case to get array values is to use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
echo implode(', ', $yourArray);
```

Comment: your answer is right i vote your answer, but just for easy understand i have post my answer.